# Почему при получении модели из базы данных не берутся коллекции C#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Есть метод, который получает элемент из таблицы базы данных PostgreSQL по id.

```
public async Task<T> Get(int id)
{
    return await table.FindAsync(id);
}
```

Есть модель элемента.

```
public sealed class Tutor
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; init; }
}
```

Почему при вызове метода возвращается модель со всеми значениями, кроме коллекции `Students`?

Вот модель ученика.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; init; }

    public string FirstName { get; init; }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что я напрямую не указал в моделях как будет устанавливаться связь, ef core сделал это за меня. В базе у учителя есть столбцы `Id | FirstName`, а у ученика `Id | FirstName | TutorId`. Все значения я задал, но все равно при вызове метода не берутся ученики.

Comment: Что значит "не берутся"?

Comment: Потому что надо указать `Include` когда дёргаете DbSet, и передать в этот метод лямбду с нужными свойствами. Еще можно это сконфигурировать в DbContext

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550556/dbset-property-of-type-class-returns-null

Comment: @Qwertiy значение остается null

Comment: @Kalmankantaja посмотрел Include, это то, что нужно, но можно ли как-то сделать универсальный Include? У меня несколько таблиц с разными моделями, и для получения данных из них есть один репозиторий с методами для взаимодействия с таблицами. Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы Include делался по умолчанию для всех свойств любой модели?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations

Comment: А там где-нибудь dispose клиента нет перед чтением?

Comment: @Qwertiy был бы где-то Dispose то эксепшен выкинуло бы при материализации коллекции т.к запрос бы не выполнился